# como hacer un backup desde un boton en visual studio c#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, windows-forms, poo

verán tengo una una bd con sus respectivas tablas y datos, ahora lo que necesito es que como pudiera hacer un backup desde un boton, tengo un procedimiento almacenado para eso

```
create procedure spCrearBackup
@direc varchar (30)
as
begin
backup database RHHH to disk = @direc with init
end
go
```

pero no se como ejecutarlo desde el botón, también quisiera poder guardar manualmente la ubicación de esa copia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el botón "buscar", que lo usare para abrir una ubicación de la copia  tengo este código

```
       FolderBrowserDialog obj = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        obj.Description = "Seleccione la ruta";
        obj.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
        if (obj.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtDirecCrear.Text = obj.SelectedPath + "\\";
        }
```

como dije quisiera poder crear un backup con una ubicación manualmente, mediante el botón "crear respaldo", mi programa esta en 3 capas como agregado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías realizar es una ejecución de una sentencia, en SQL por medio de la clases de C#. Te dejo el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
/* Declaras tu conexión */
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConStrBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
    /*En una variable formulas la sentencia para ejecutar, en esta caso hasta se le envía parametros */
    var query = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE {0} TO DISK='{1}'", 
        sqlConStrBuilder.InitialCatalog, backupFileName);

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        /* posteriormente, abres la conexión y ejecutas la sentencia*/
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

te recomiendo siempre, controlar los errores. Espero te sirva.